# Getting blank page instead of custom 404 error page?

Tags: tomcat, custom-error-pages

I have created custom error page with some message. I added this html page in `web.xml` file. I put this html file under `webapp/WEB-INF/error/404.html`. But after running it shows blank page without giving any message. Please help me.

```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `<location>` tag needs to be an URI that is reachable through HTTP.

So if, for example, your application runs under `http://host.com/application/index.html` and you place your error HTML at `http://host.com/application/error.html` your `location` tag would need to look like this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Also note that you may omit the `<error-code>` after Servlet API 3.0 (in case of Tomcat that would be at least version 7) - this allows you to have one general error page.